# If localStorage data is erased from one browser, is it erased from another too?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

What happened: I created a program to keep track of payments from my students, client side only.

The program was running, but needed improvements. So while I was working on it, (writting code and checking it on Chrome), I thought of starting using it too (bad idea). I opened it on a different browser (that I never use), and started storing the payments there.

Today, on checking it, all the information I had entered was gonne.

I never cleared the browser data, I never did anything on the program to erase the data. I was only opening it, entering data and closing it. The browser is Opera version 48.0.2685.52

I did reset the program (that would erase all data stored in localStorage) while I had it opened on another browser: Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100, since I thought every browser would have its own localStorage.

For sure I don't want that happening again (luckily I had an old fashion paper copy of the payments).

So my question is: If I have many browsers opened in a computer (windows 10 home) and erase localStorage data from a program running in one browser, will it be erased from the other browser too?

Reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage, I got that there is a Storage Object, linked to the page origin.

Now I have no idea what they mean by that hahaha, or that "It should be noted that data stored in either localStorage or sessionStorage is specific to the protocol of the page.", which for me is chinese -traditional- since I am not a professional programmer.

I would appreciate any help (to understand how things work, or what they are), mainly written like you were talking to a 7 year old, not very bright, who has a passion for trying to write computer programs that work. :)

UPDATE_ The code I am using to reset all values is just setting a certain piece of localStorage information to a certain value:

```
function resetsAllValues(){

if(window.confirm("This will delete all data.\nThis action can not be 
undone!\nAre you sure you want to proceed?")){
            localStorage.setItem("Stu1", "undefined");
}//closes if
else {return;}//closes else
```

Then I check if that piece of information has that value, and if it does, I reset the values by localStorage.setItem(default name, default value);

Comment: `It should be noted that data stored in either localStorage or sessionStorage is specific to the protocol of the page` - that basically just means that if you store data for a page served with `http://`, it is not visible from the same page served over `https://` and vice versa , if that makes sense to you.

Comment: @KarlReid, Ok yes, that is kind of understandable, thank you. But that doesn't answer my question, does it? (if it does then I am in the darkest night about all this).

Comment: Other than that, `localStorage` is not shared between browsers on the same machine, so if you didn't clear your browser history on Opera I'm not sure why the storage would go missing. Maybe give more detail about how you `reset the program`, or share some code, there isn't enough information here to diagnose.

Comment: "I thought every browser would have it's own localStorage" - correct.  Data is distinct / unique to each browser.

Comment: @KarlReid, I updated the question, with the code. If localStorage is not shared between browsers on the same machine, then I have no clue about what happened. Thanks. :)

Comment: As an aside, I would _never every_ rely on localStorage, personally.  It's a convenience, can be handy / useful, but I would always have a "backup" plan for getting / storing the data.

Comment: @cale_b, well, I had the same instincts, that is why I had a paper copy! hahah, today I was trying to find a way to write the information on localStorage to a file using only javascript, since I am new to all this, I found some answers and I will have to do some learning to try and implement them. Thank you for your advice. :)

Comment: Well Opera and Chrome both use Blink for their browser engine, but it still would be really weird if they stored their localstorage data in the same location on your harddrive.

Comment: Well I don't know, I read now that blink is the underlying web browser engine used by Chrome and Opera. The thing is that all information disappeared and I have to find a way to back up this info using only js. Thanks for your comment.